# adb Logcat: Most of the messages are lost (due to length)

Tags: android, adb, logcat, android-debug

I'm trying to debug an android App with adb. But unfortunately most of the messages from the log are like this:

```
W/AEE ( 0): some logs have been lost (5046 bytes estimated)
```

It goes like this almost all the time and I can not capture the actual messages from my App. I'm on sony xperia with Android 4.4.2. Do you know why it happens? and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: did you try to filter your logs by TAG or PACKAGE ?

Comment: I did. Then it shows nothing due to loss of the messages. I use: adb logcat  MyApp:D *:S

Comment: are u using that through prompt? Maybe using it with GUI can solve your problem

Comment: how about making your messages shorter? There is a `#define LOGGER_ENTRY_MAX_PAYLOAD 4076` in `include/log/logger.h`. Any log message longer than that gets truncated.

Comment: @AlexP. I think it's smth with the device. It happens not only for my own messages.

Comment: @StefanoVuerich Unfortunately in the GUI I see the same messages I see in the terminal. Most of them are warnings about lost messages..